# PrimeNg- p-dropdown tooltip on hover

Tags: angular, angular7, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have a `p-dropdown` component on my App. Its' configured like this:

```
  <p-dropdown
                 [showTransitionOptions]="'0ms'"
                 [hideTransitionOptions]="'0ms'"
                 dropdownIcon="fa fa-angle-down"
                (onChange)="onChangePrimaryTarget($event)"
                 [options]="targetsLookup"
                 formControlName="target"
                 placeholder="Select a Primary Target"
                 tooltip="'getTargetDescription($event)'">
</p-dropdown>
```

I need to show the description for each target on `Hover` I read the `PrimeNg` documentation and says that the `tooltip` configuration does that. The problem is that I'm not seing anything:

[image]

What I need to see is something like this:

[image]

With the black `tooltip` on hover.

I already tried to hardcode some text on the `tooltip` and still doesn't show anything.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: use "Custom Content" from https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown

Comment: can you put an example? I'm not figuring out how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could user PrimeNG [Tooltip](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tooltip) along with template for the drop down (see Custom Content [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown))

```
<p-dropdown
    [showTransitionOptions]="'0ms'"
    [hideTransitionOptions]="'0ms'"
    dropdownIcon="fa fa-angle-down"
    (onChange)="onChangePrimaryTarget($event)"
    [options]="targetsLookup"
    formControlName="target"
    placeholder="Select a Primary Target">
        <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
            <span style="vertical-align:middle">{{item.label}}</span>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-target pTemplate="item">
            <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="position: relative;height:25px;" pTooltip="{{getTargetDescription(target)}}" tooltipPosition="top">
                <span style="font-size:14px;float:right;margin-top:4px">{{target.label}}</span>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do was to do this -->

```
        <p-dropdown
            id="clientId"
            name="clientId"
            (onChange)="selectClient($event)"
            [options]="clientId"
            [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
            appendTo="body"
        >            
            <ng-template let-client pTemplate="item">
                <div [pTooltip]="client.testName" tooltipPosition="right">
                    {{ client.label }}
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-dropdown>
```

My requirement was to have a tooltip that dynamically changes it's value on hover over the dropdown options.
Here is what I did in my TS file -

```
 this.clientId = res.data.clients.map((client) => {
                    return {
                        label: client.clientName,
                        value: client.clientId,
                        testName: this.testConfig.testName,
                    };
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try binding tooltip

`[tooltip]="getTargetDescription($event)"` // This can be the reason.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am looking for the answer for the same issue too